# Mysql Union time V.S. separate query one by one

Tags: mysql, sql, union

If I have n queries q1, q2, q3 ... qn and each of them running t1, t2, t3 ... tn as the running time.

Also I have another query  q1 UNION ALL q2 UNION ALL q3 .... UNION ALL qn and running time is tu

compare tu and t1+t2+t3+...+tn, which one will be faster in theory? I know doing experiment is the best way to find out, but I need to hear specialist voice on the theory. Thanks

Comment: This sounds like an exam question.

Comment: It is a practical need. Need to consider implementation strategy

Comment: did you try executing each version? or comparing the execution plans?

Comment: `n` selects has the disadvantage of `n` round trips to the database, `UNION` has the disadvantage of having to do a `DISTINCT`. In theory, none of them have an advantage or disadvantage in all cases. `UNION ALL` should be faster than both though since it eliminates both downsides.

Comment: I can do it if Union strategy is theoretically faster.

Comment: There's a big difference between `UNION` and `UNION ALL` here, though...

Comment: changed question to UNION ALL

Comment: @JNK Yes, but I thought it was worth adding because `n` selects is more similar to `UNION ALL` than `UNION`, since the `n` selects would require writing `DISTINCT` in code to do the same thing as `UNION`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UNION` operator requires duplicate tuples (rows) be removed the result set before any rows are returned. That's effectively a SORT UNIQUE operation. That's relatively inexpensive for small result sets, but for massive sets, it can be resource intensive on the server time (i.e. take a long time.)

In theory, combining the queries with a `UNION ALL` operator rather than a `UNION` operator would be fastest, since it would eliminate (*n*-1) roundtrips to the database, vs running queries separately. But for large values of *n*, you are going to run into practical limits on the size of the SQL text (max packet size).

Given the choice between `UNION` operator and separate queries, for a large result set, the separate queries are going to be less resource intensive on the server side.

In short, it's really a tradeoff between the heavy lifting for each query, vs. the heavy lifting of a SORT UNIQUE operation.

Answer (score 2):

Since `UNION ALL` with n subqueries could be executed as n selects, a smart DBMS should be able do at most the same work as n separate selects.

That leaves round trip time, which is `n * rtt` for n queries and `rtt` for the `UNION ALL`.

In theory, a smart DBMS should always be answer a single `UNION ALL` faster than n separate queries.
In practice, as usual, all bets are off without testing.