# SQL select five of this and five of that

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Is there any way to do a single select which gets the 10 newest cars from a car table, where 5 of them are red and 5 of them are blue?

The best I can come up with are two selects and a programmatic merge:

```
red  = query("select * from cars where color = 'red'  order by when desc limit 5")
blue = query("select * from cars where color = 'blue' order by when desc limit 5")
all = merge(red, blue)
```

Comment: You have tagged this with both MySQL and PostgreSQL, what database are you using? By tagging it with a the correct RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: How are/is your table(s) structured?

Comment: maybe try `union all`?

Answer (score 2):

For MySQL try:

```
select * from cars where color = 'blue' order by releasedate desc limit 5
Union
select * from cars where color = 'red' order by releasedate desc limit 5
```

Comment: Is a union select as expensive as two separate selects?

Comment: I think UNION ALL is better still. Here's a previous question specific to the performance comparison between union and separate queries http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590596/mysql-union-time-v-s-separate-query-one-by-one

Answer (score 0):

Since, mysql doesn't support `CTE` and `Window Function` like any other RDBMS, you can use correlated subquery on this,

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    Cars a
WHERE   a.Color IN ('Red', 'Blue') AND
        (
            SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM    Cars b
            WHERE   b.Color IN ('Red', 'Blue') AND
                    a.Color = b.Color AND
                    a.time >= b.time
        ) <= 5
```

---

**POSTGRESQL**

```
WITH carList
AS
(
    SELECT  Col1, Col2, Col3, Color,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Color ORDER BY time DESC) rn
    FROM    tableName
)
SELECT  Col1, Col2, Col3, Color
FROM    carList
WHERE   Color IN ('Red', 'Blue') AND
        RN <= 5
```

- [PostgreSQL CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/queries-with.html)
- [PostgreSQL Window Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html)

Comment: @J W: Interesting! How does one solve this with Postgres/Window? I am considering switching to Postgres at some point.

Comment: @forthrin see my updated answer. `Col1,.., Col3` are just sample column names. hehe