# Adding a variable to a query's result to indicate the phrases it matches within OR statements?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, boolean-logic

What is a simple way to add a variable to the results which match specific portions of a `SELECT` query? There are several `OR` statements in the query and I'd like to indicate which of the queries criteria a particular value matched on.

The only ideas that are coming to mind right now require running subsequent queries/functions, but since there are quite a number of `OR` statements within the query that would probably affect the performance too much.

Here's a very simplified example of the query:

```
$User_Waist = "30";
$User_Hip = "41";

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM SizeChart WHERE FIND_IN_SET($User_Hip, Hip_Measurement) > 0 OR FIND_IN_SET($User_Waist, Waist_Measurement) > 0;
");   
$stmt->bindValue(':Waist_Measurement', $Waist_Measurement, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':Hip_Measurement', $Hip_Measurement, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();         
if ($stmt->columnCount()) {
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
        echo $row['Size'].' '.$row['Waist_Measurement'].' '.$row['Hip_Measurement'], "<br />";  
   }
}
```

Comment: kind of a hack, but you could do a union select, where you set a value based on the returned row -> `SELECT *,'hip' as \`match\` FROM SizeChart WHERE FIND_IN_SET(:User_Hip, Hip_Measurement) > 0 UNION SELECT *,'waist' as \`match\` FROM SizeChart WHERE FIND_IN_SET(:User_Waist, Waist_Measurement) > 0`. Then use `$row['match']` to show what matched / returned the row.

Comment: @Sean - I hadn't even known about the UNION SELECT :-) It looks like it's working with one slight glitch - it's returning separate $row[] results for each $row['match'] (i.e. a size matches on both measurements) :-( Any idea how I can combine them so that they still connect properly to the db rows? Also, any downsides to it that you can think of?

Comment: I am a hobbyist, with no official training, so unfortunately I don't know directly of any downsides, other than what I read from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12590793/689579.

Comment: To deal with your duplicate issue, you could start it with an `AND` to select where both match -> `SELECT *,'both' as \`match\` FROM SizeChart WHERE FIND_IN_SET(:User_Hip, Hip_Measurement) > 0 AND FIND_IN_SET(:User_Waist, Waist_Measurement) > 0 UNION SELECT *,'hip' as \`match\` FROM SizeChart WHERE FIND_IN_SET(:User_Hip, Hip_Measurement) > 0 UNION SELECT *,'waist' as \`match\` FROM SizeChart WHERE FIND_IN_SET(:User_Waist, Waist_Measurement) > 0`. According to the answer I linked before, all duplicates are removed, so you should only return them under `both` and not under `hip`/`waist`.

Comment: Here is the docs on `UNION` syntax -> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html My suggestion comes from the bottom -> `Use of an additional column also enables you to determine which SELECT each row comes from. Extra columns can provide other identifying information as well, such as a string that indicates a table name.`

Comment: @Sean - Creating both AND + OR queries would definitely do the trick for this simplified example, but I have a feeling that it is going to get way too cumbersome because each of these type of queries actually calls a lot more columns :-(